# How can I Insert data to my table from a comma separated text?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, where-clause

I have a long TEXT with ID's inside it like:

```
$IDLIST TEXT // ("101,102,103)"
```

I want to insert the matching UniqueID and some other parameters into my message_customers table.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `piro_customer_monitor`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `PCMMessageCustomersALtInsert`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PCMMessageCustomersALtInsert`(
    $Message_ID     INT(11),
    $IDLIST         TEXT,
    $Is_Read        tinyint(4),
    $Read_When      datetime,
    $Created_When       datetime,
    $Is_Active      tinyint(4),
    OUT $ID         INT(11) 
)
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 
CONCAT=('
    INSERT INTO cm_message_customers (Message_ID, Subscription_Unique_ID, Read_When, Created_When) 
    SELECT
        $Message_ID,
        cs.Unique_ID,
        $Read_When,
        $Created_When
    FROM
        customer_subscriptions cs
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS(cs.ID, '$IDLIST');
');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SET $ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I have an ID which is in the list($IDLIST), I want to insert it's Unique_ID, from the customer_subscriptions table to cm_message_customers table along with other parameters.

Comment: You don't have access to any application-level code?

Comment: I have, I just wanted to do this way.